# Returning index value of list object?

Tags: c#, list, object

for the life of me, I cannot figure this out. Basically I am trying to make a search function with an unsorted list of objects. No matter what I try, the location returns -1. When I look at the logic, it makes sense to me, but maybe I've been staring at my screen for too long. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
            public static int ContactSearchFirst(List<Contact> contactList, string userInput)
    {
        int location = -1;
        for (int index = 0; index < contactList.Count && location == -1; index++)
        {
            if (contactList[index].FirstName.ToUpper().Equals(userInput.ToUpper()))
            {
                location = index;
            }
        }
        return location;
    }
```

Comment: This code has a couple of issues. Which language are you using? Improvements depend on which language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using C#, then the whole loop is un-necessary. You can simply use the [`List<T>.FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx) method:

```
public static int ContactSearchFirst(List<Contact> contactList,
                                     string userInput)
{
    return contactList
        .FindIndex(c => 
            c.FirstName.Equals(userInput,
                               StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

You may also want to trim the input so that leading/trailing spaces don't cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You would only get a new location value if the following is ever true, so maybe it never is true:

```
if (contactList[index].FirstName.ToUpper().Equals(userInput.ToUpper()))
```

Comment: If I enter "Bob" into contactList[index].FirstName, and in userInput, it still returns -1.

Comment: When doing that test, if you print out the boolean value of the "if" logic, does it print out "true"?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the parameters are being passed incorrectly when the function is called.

If you are using visual studio you can easily check this by setting a break point in your code and inspecting the contactList and userInput variables.